# Detect when Firefox plug-in is blocked

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, mozilla

Is there a way through JavaScript or a web service to see if a plug-in installed in Firefox is being blocked by Mozilla? In particular, on my web site, I want to be able to tell if Mozilla is blocking an outdated version of Adobe Flash and adjust our UI accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address that Firefox uses to download the blocklist is defined as `extensions.blocklist.url` preference:

> https://addons.mozilla.org/blocklist/3/%APP_ID%/%APP_VERSION%/%PRODUCT%/%BUILD_ID%/%BUILD_TARGET%/%LOCALE%/%CHANNEL%/%OS_VERSION%/%DISTRIBUTION%/%DISTRIBUTION_VERSION%/%PING_COUNT%/%TOTAL_PING_COUNT%/%DAYS_SINCE_LAST_PING%/

Fortunately, not all of these parameters are required, this address will work to download the current blocklist:

> https://addons.mozilla.org/blocklist/3/%7Bec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384%7D/21.0/

This is the ID of Firefox and the version number of the current release, so the blocklist could be different for other Mozilla applications and other Firefox versions. Looking through https://addons.mozilla.org/blocked/, there are some items listed as "for Firefox version n.n.n and higher", some are listed as "for Firefox and SeaMonkey" and others again as "for all Mozilla applications". Still, it seems that the blocklist for the current Firefox version should be the most complete one.

You can download and process this file in a web service, then adjust the behavior of your web application accordingly.

Comment: We really need to request and parse a file from mozilla.org instead of simply referencing a local browser property?  Seeing that the plugin is on the blocked list doesn't mean it's blocked on the current session—the user may have enabled the blocked plugin.

Comment: @Seanonymous: If your goal is figuring out whether a particular plugin works then the website can just try it out (while keeping click-to-play in mind). Reading out the configuration of the user's browser isn't something it can do, and it's not what the question was about.

Comment: The question stated "I want to be able to tell if Mozilla is blocking an outdated version of Adobe Flash and adjust our UI accordingly" which to me means the desire is to know if the Flash Player is being blocked by the browser the code is running in, i.e., if it's blocked by the browser and the user has not disabled the block by activating the plugin.   Attempting to load Flash content and then falling back on something else if it fails isn't as streamlined as checking navigator.plugins.